# Ohm's law; LED Circuit; measuring current using a multimeter (ammeter)

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, light-emitting-diodes

I have a $9V$ power supply, connected to a $2.37k \Omega$ resistor followed by a LED to the ground. I want to use Ohm's law to predict my current. So $\frac{9V}{2.37k \Omega} = 3.79 mA$.

When I measure the current between the positive $9V$ terminal and the resistor the value measured is $2.88 mA$.  I can cross check the $2.88 mA$ in ohms law and it still checks out.

What is causing this difference?

Comment: There is a voltage drop across the LED. This article may help you? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_circuit

Answer (score 0):

The led also provides some resistance. Therefore, the net resistance is more than $2.37k \Omega$

This would give you a current less than $3.79mA$ in the circuit.